# tSQLt - OneTimeSetup

Tags: sql-server, tsqlt

Does anyone know if it is possible to perform a One Time Setup using tSQLt?

From what I've seen in the documentation there is a SetUp SP for the TestClass Mechanism which runs before each test is executed but I can't see anything to the OneTimeSetup test fixture in NUnit.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achieve with this functionality?

Comment: I'm looking to set up a TestClass where the Setup Procedure runs ones and then you have split your assertions into separate procedures.

The functionality is of an acceptance test (running through  a single module in the database and then running each assertion independently)

Comment: It looks to me like you are not in need of a setup per se, but rather a multi-assertion test. I've to think about that. As tSQLt is primarily a unit testing framework, it goes against several of its core principles. But I can see where you are coming from.

Answer (score 2):

One of the core principles of tSQLt is to not allow for any side-effects. A class level setup would violate that principle. Therefore this functionality is not likely to be added soon. However, I've been thinking about adding a capability to allow for tests to be executed outside of a transaction and have started the work to implement an undo framework. But currently there are more pressing concerns atop of the list.